# Is there any computational difference between while and for loops?

Tags: java, loops, big-o

Just wondering if there is any computational difference between:

```
for(;condition;) {
    //task
}
```

and

```
while(condition) {
    //task
}
```

Comment: No.................

Comment: In both structures the Condition is tested one more time then the execution of body, so there is no computational difference.

Comment: Try compiling both of these, and looking at the byte code.  Let us all know if you see any difference at all.

Comment: The only practical difference between that kind of for-loop, and a while-loop, is if you use `continue`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is **`no difference`** as in both the cases **`Java compiler generates the same byte code`** . If you look on the byte code when I used `for loop`:

```
  0: bipush        11
  2: istore_1
  3: goto          9
  6: iinc          1, -1
  9: iload_1
 10: bipush        10
 12: if_icmpgt     6
 15: return
```

The above byte code genearated for the code below :

```
    int a = 11;
    for (; a > 10;) {
        a--;
    }
```

And same byte code:

```
   Code:
      0: bipush        11
      2: istore_1
      3: goto          9
      6: iinc          1, -1
      9: iload_1
     10: bipush        10
     12: if_icmpgt     6
     15: return
```

Has generated by the compiler when I used `while loop`

```
    int a = 11;
    while (a > 10) {
        a--;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The only difference between `for` and `while` is the syntax. Java will compile them to the exactly same code so there's no computational difference. [Here is an article in the matter](https://www.mkyong.com/java/while-loop-for-loop-and-iterator-performance-test-java/).

Comment: Not sure if that article is the best one, next to that it doesn't really show if it compiles to exactly the same code. It shows only a sketchy benchmark.

Comment: You are right, Admin Bera's answer is a better proof.